# Issue re-applying a filter on workbook close

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code in the ThisWorkbook section:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Sheet("Sheet2").AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub
```

I assumed the second line would re-apply the filter I have set in the AutoFilter on Sheet 2.

I have data feeding in to Sheet 1, and Sheet 2 reads that data and filters it. The document is then working with AutoHotkey to: open, take more data, save and close on a timer. I just need it so that when the document closes it looks at that filter on Sheet2 and re-applies it.

I have tried:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Sheet2.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub
```

But that did not work. After looking through some VBA stuff, it seemed changing `Sheet2.AutoFilter.ApplyFilter` to `Sheet("Sheet2").AutoFilter.Applyfilter` would do the trick. But now I just get *Compile Error: sub or function not defined*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sheet("Sheet2").AutoFilter.Applyfilter` should be `Sheets("Sheet2").AutoFilter.Applyfilter` (missing the "s").  `Sheet` isn't something recognized by VBA, so it thinks that's a subroutine or function you defined somewhere else. `Sheets()` however, is what you're looking for.

`Sheet2.[whatever]` does have applications in VBA, *however* it's NOT necessarily going to refer to the sheet named `"Sheet2"`.  `Sheet2` refers to the second worksheet created in the workbook.  If you create three worksheets, and rename them to like "Fun Page 1", "Fun Page 4", "Fun Page 8", `Sheet2.AutoFilter...` will run on whatever sheet you created second (which could be the one named "Fun Page 4".)

By using `Sheets("Fun Page 4").AutoFilter...`, the code is telling VB to look for the sheet named "Fun Page 4", not the one that was created 1st, 2nd, etc...

Does that make sense?

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I was able to successfully save the workbook without error. I need to wait for new data to load in before I will know for sure if this solved. Thank you! Will mark as answered once I confirm.... Also, stupid S....

Comment: Well I discovered the big issue is apparently with my autohotkey script. I use a command to close the workbook in AHK, and it seems through doing it this way it doesn't close the same as if closed by the user.

Your changes work if i manually close the workbook.

Comment: @Aldentec, You could add the same code to your AHK close commands I'd think, and it'd do what you wanted.

Comment: Just curious, do you know an easy way to make the workbook close after say 20 seconds of being open? If I can do that, I can remove that part from the AHK script and allow Excel to do it itself, in turn it should be able to apply filter at that point.

Comment: Interesting idea, will test this out.

Comment: You could add a timer, sure.  [Here's one page](http://www.teachexcel.com/free-excel-macros/m-13,close-workbook-time-limit.html) I found that gives some info, and [another](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/211053-visual-basic-applications-close-file-after-period-time.html) that should guide you in the right direction.  Although from what I understand, using timers in Excel isn't so straight forward always, so I recommend looking for an alternative first (such as adding the same closing code to your AHK).

Comment: Thanks Bruce! Do you have any experience with AHK by chance? I am trying to work this out but struggling.

Comment: @Aldentec - unfortunately I do not :/  ...but perhaps others on SO do.  You could start a new question and give details on what you've tried, what has/hasn't worked.  The main question I think would be how to run a `Workbook_BeforeClose` event when not exiting Excel manually (File -> Exit, or clicking "X").

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I will do this.